# Date conversion in typescript with mentioned format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am getting value from backend like 2021-07-21T16:11:58:8209904 I want to display this value like 21 July 2021.Can anyone help me to convert this value in typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use great library momentjs (https://momentjs.com).

Smth like this:

```
import moment from 'moment';

const date = moment('2021-07-21T16:11:58');
print(date.format('Do MMMM YYYY'));
```

-> 30th July 2021